# ESLINT based on envirement

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Is there a way I can only run the eslint based on certain envirements? I would like to only run it based on if a certain query string is there. I am using it for a .NET and React.js application.
Thanks!

I couldn't find anything about this topic and would love to hear that it's possible.

Comment: Linting is something you do to code before or during the build phase. By the time the app is getting query strings passed to it, it's already been built. Unless you're talking about a specific build framework that is available with a web frontend...

Comment: Okay, thank you Heretic Monkey!